# Using single elastic search connection object across multiple python files?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, connection

How can I use a single Elastic Search connection object in multiple files of python? I tried making it global but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the Es object as an **argument**. So when you call a method or a function from a different python file, you pass this object as function/method argument. I doubt if you can achieve something like that by using global variables.